# Same height for all rows in SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a `List` in which all rows have the same height

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var content = ["row1", "row2\nrow2\nrow2", "row3"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<content.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(self.content[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Row1 and row3 should have the same height with row2
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set .frame for Text(self.content[index]) ?

Comment: @KeyurTailor I do not know the frame, the height should be according to the biggest height in the list

Comment: @KeshuR. Not really, `.defaultMinListRowHeight` can be used to set a minim height, but I do not know the height for my rows

Comment: You need to calculate the maximum `height` for the longest string in your content and then use `frame` for `Text` with that calculated `height`.

Comment: @Kamran I used `Text` view for this example, my real rows are much complex than that, a couple of `Text` views arranged with `HStack` and `VStack`, so this would not work

Comment: For this kind of requirement, you need to calculate the height based on all those views in a row.

Comment: @Kamran yeah, how to do that :))

Comment: Try to create an array of ListItem heights. Find maximum height from the array and reload your List with maximum height for ListItem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a Workaround.
I have used geometryReader for calculate content height.Once we get the max height for the content, with the help of preferences update the cell.

```
struct TestView: View {
@State var content = ["row1", "row2\nrow2\nrow2", "row3"]
@State var rowHeight: CGFloat = 0

var body: some View {
  List {
      ForEach(0..<content.count, id: \.self) { index in
        Text(self.content[index])
            .frame(minHeight: self.rowHeight)  // set height as max height
            .background(
                GeometryReader{ (proxy) in
                    Color.clear.preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size)  
            })
            .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { (preferences) in
                let currentSize: CGSize = preferences
                if (currentSize.height > self.rowHeight) {
                    self.rowHeight = currentSize.height     //As height get change upto max height , put value in self.rowHeight
                }
            }
      }
  }
}
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGSize
    static var defaultValue: Value = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        nextValue()
    }
}
```

[image: output]